# Can't subscribe to Push notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

I'm trying to subscribe to PushManager to send push notification, but I'm always getting an error when calling subscribe.

This is my subscribe call

```
registration.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true })
  .then(function (subscription) { /* ... */})
  .catch(function (err) { /* ... */})
```

Nothing weird as you can see, and that call is always throwing

> DOMException: Registration failed - push service error

I'm not sure why is that. 
What I've checked so far

- I have a `gcm_sender_id` property in my `manifest.json`.
- The permision for notification is granted in the client.
- `registration.pushManager.getSubscription()` always get `null` and subscribe always throw the above error.

What else should I look? Any help to succesfully subscribe to push notifications is welcome, by the way, I'm using chrome 55, if you need more info just let me know.

**EDIT**: All of the registration code is [here](https://github.com/YerkoPalma/blank-app-shell/blob/master/src/utils.js) on the `registerServiceWorker` function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have registered the service worker properly, using something like :

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js', {
                scope: '/'
            });
```

I suggest you use a relative path for your service worker like I did instead of using *window.location.origin* like you did in your code and it is always better to keep the serviceworker file at the **root**.

Use this approach to subscribe for push and get an endpoint.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready
            .then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
                return serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
                    userVisibleOnly: true
                });
            })
            .then(function(subscription) {console.log(subscription.endpoint);});
```

If it still doesn't work:
-Try unregistering the existing worker from chrome://serviceworker-internals and make sure you close all tabs when you do that.

If it still doesn't work:
-Try creating a new chrome profile by clicking on your name in the top right corner of chrome. (I faced this once)

Check [this](http://simple-push-demo.appspot.com) code for your reference.

Comment: I used `window.location.origin` because when someone navigated to another route, I was getting an error of service worker not found, maybe the `scope` option would fix that. The rest of the code is equivalent to your answer

Comment: After some search I found my solution. I was using a wrong `gcm_sender_id` in my `manifest.json` file. I used the project ID in google developer console, when I [changed it by the project number](https://github.com/YerkoPalma/blank-app-shell/commit/34cd59cfb37e6247f3d8bdc69b94e926753052ad#diff-4b1eb3dc48c4e16d49db5b42298fe654), it worked!

Comment: :) Good for you!  BUT that shouldn't have been the problem. You'll face the problem with incorrect gcm_sender_id only when you are triggering a push and not when you are subscribing. I am guessing the root scope did the trick for you! :)

Comment: I don't think so, because I haven't made that change yet. And the gcm key that is used only when a push is sended is the gcm api key registered in the server, different from the id for the manifest. In fact, if you try to subscribe without a gcm_sender_id property in the manifest it will throw a different error

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention something that happened to me related to DOMException while subscribing the browser/web push user with FCM push service which is, the subscription was working like magic however as I was testing my app I was hitting FCM push service/server a lot. this led to a TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS error which can be checked via [chrome://gcm-internals](http://chrome://gcm-internals). The solution was pretty logical, just create a new profile/user on chrome.

FCM was rejecting any registration request from previous chrome user and I believe FCM was considering it as a SPAM or someone hacking their server. Thanks to @Dhruv Batheja for bringing my attention to that.

Comment: :) - - - - - -(: